# How to get MATIC token on Goerli Networks?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, polygon, matic

I need help about getting Matic token or Swap from Goerli ETH to Goerli Matic token for development. I found this https://faucet.polygon.technology/ but it didn't worked and I tried uniswap didn't find the testnet goerli just found scroll-alpha networks.

Did anyone knows how to get MATIC token for staking on Goerli Network?

Thank's

Point of problems : I need MATIC token on goerli networks

Comment: I tried using that faucet polygon give but it returned `insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Answer (score 0):

For the deployment purpose you can use Sepolia network, get faucet from: https://sepoliafaucet.com/

Matic is for Polygon, it not use for Ethereum testnet for deployment